# Placing a fixed number of points on a curve to make the finite second derivative constant

Tags: algorithms

I am given a 1D curve $f(x)$ that starts at $a$ and ends at $b$. I have $n$ points I have to place on the curve, and I have to place two points at $a$ and $b$, respectively. Is there a way to place points $a=x_1<...<x_n=b$ along the line so that the finite second derivative (i.e., $f(x_{i-1})-2f(x_i)+f(x_{i+1})$) is constant for all $i=2,...,n-1$? In my particular problem, $f(x)=-\log(x)$ on the interval $[\frac{1}{t},1]$. Maybe this additional structure makes the problem more tractable.

Comment: What have you tried?  What are your thoughts?  What's the motivation or context in which you ran into this problem?

Comment: What became of this question of yours?

Comment: I am a bit surprised by your choice of accepted answer. What do you
think is wrong with mine that solves the problem algebraically with
the formula $x_i=f^{-1}(f(a)-(i-1)u+c\frac{(i-2)(i-1)}{2})$ and
determines the value of $u=f(a)-f(x_2)$ from that of $c$, or the
reverse, with the simple linear equation $f(b)=f(a)-(n-1)u+c\frac{(n-2)(n-1)}{2}$.
It seems much more precise and much less costly to compute than the other
answer, that requires many iterations to produce only numerical
approximations. I am also wondering about the definition of finite
second derivative. Did I err in the algebra?

Comment: @D.W. Is the formula used by the OP known as finite second derivative anywhere? That seems strange: derivatives are supposed to be about the variations of a function in relation to the variations of the variables, but the variables are nowhere to be seen in that formula. I may not know all details of the various ways maths is taught in the world, but that seems pretty standard.

Comment: @babou, I think you're quite right.  Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

### In a nutshell

The problem can be solved algebraically by considering the equations as
defining $y_i=f(x_i)$. This gives $n-1$ equations with $n$ unknowns ($y_i$ for $i\in[2,n-1]$, and the values of $c$ and $u$ defined below),
resulting in the abitrary choice of one value. The answers are given
by the formula
$$x_i=f^{-1}(f(a)-(i-1)u+c\frac{(i-2)(i-1)}{2})$$

and the value of $u=f(a)-f(x_2)$ is determined from that of the
constant finite second derivative $c$, or the reverse, with the linear
relation
$$f(b)=f(a)-(n-1)u+c\frac{(n-2)(n-1)}{2}$$

However I wonder if the formula used is really that of a finite second
derivative.

### Full proof

*With the formula used*, your question seems rather tractable, and solvable algebraically.

Like the previous answer, I note $c$ the value of the constant finite second derivative, as defined in the question (though this is further discussed below).

You should see it as a set of equations in $y$, with $y=f(x)$.
If you note $y_i=f(x_i)$, you get a set of $n-2$ equations
 $$y_{i-1}-2y_{i}+y_{i+1}=c\;\; \text{ for }i\in [2,n-1]$$
with $n-1$ unknown : $y_{i} \text{ for }i\in [2,n-1]$ and $c$, given
that you have $y_1=f(a)$ and $y_n=f(b)

This probably means an infinity of solutions, which may means that you
can choose arbitrarily one of the values, for example that of $c$.
I have not worked out the equations.

However, given the strictly monotonically decreasing function $f$ of your example, you have the
additional constaints that:
$$ \forall i\in[2,n-1], \;\;y_i\in(f(a), f(b)) \;\wedge\; y_i>y_{i+1} $$

One way to start resolving it is by defining $u_i=y_i-y_{i+1}$ and $v_i=y_i-y_{i+2}$ for $i\in [1,n-2]$. Then the equations become
$y_i-2(y_i-u_1)+(y_i-v_i)=c$ which simplifies into
$2u_i-v_i=c$, from which we derive $v_i-u_i=u_i-c$.

From the definition of $u_i$, $u_{i+1}$, and $v_i$, we derive $u_{i+1}=v_i-u_i$. Hence $u_{i+1}=u_i-c$. From this recurrence relation we get $u_i=u-(i-1)c$, where $u$ is defined as $u=u_1=y_1-y_2$.

So we now have the simpler recurrence relation: $y_{i+1}=y_i-u_i=y_i-(u-(i-1)c)$, i.e., $y_{i+1}=y_i-u+(i-1)c$, from which we get
\begin{align}
 y_i&=y_1+\sum_{k=1}^{i-1}{u_k} \\
 &=y_1+\sum_{k=1}^{i-1}{-u+(k-1)c} \\
 &=y_1-(i-1)u+c\sum_{k=0}^{i-2}{k} \\
y_i&=y_1-(i-1)u+c\frac{(i-2)(i-1)}{2}
\end{align}
This last formula is valid for $i\in[1,n-1]$, since the recurrence formula is defined for $y_{i+1}$ and the equations used were defined for all values of $i$ up to $n-2$.
We must now consider $y_n$. Since $v_{n-2}-u_{n-2}=u_{n-2}-c$, we get $y_n=y_{n-1}-(u_{n-2}-c)$.
Since $u_{n-2}=u-(n-3)c$, we finally obtain
$\begin{align}
 y_n&=y_1-(n-2)u+c\frac{(n-3)(n-2)}{2}-u+(n-3)c+c \\
 &=y_1-(n-1)u+c\frac{(n-2)(n-1)}{2}
\end{align}
$

Hence our formula for $y_i$ is correct for all $i\in[1,n]$.

*Note: a much simpler technique for $y_n$ would be to consider an extra point at $y_{n+1}$ on the curve, so as to have more equations. But all this was already written when I thought of it.*

Considering that we have the last constraint $y_n=f(b)$, we can use it
with the equation for $y_n$ to determine $u=y_1-y_2$ if we wish to
choose $c$, or to determine $c$ if we rather choose $u$.

This is easily rephrased into the result given at the beginning of this answer. Then it should be easy to apply it to the example in the
question.
However, I do wonder whether all this is useful, because I am not sure this is the question you intended to
ask.

The reason is that the formula given in the question is not the formula of the finite
second derivative. The proper formula is something like:
$$4\times\frac{f(x_{i-1})-2f(x_i)+f(x_{i+1})}{(x_{i+1}-x_{i-1})^2}$$

See for example [higher-order finite differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences) in wikipedia. Though I am not sure that even this corrected formula is meaningful as, the formula normally given assumes that $x_i= (x_{i-1}+x_{i+1})/2$. But the expression you use is somewhere between the formulae for forward and backward finite differences, and should thus be usable with some meaning.

Thus, if I am correct, you should edit your question to make it consistent, either by
removing the reference to the finite
second derivative, or by using the proper formula for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach.  Set $x_1=a$, $x_2=a'$, choose a fixed value $c$ that you want the second derivative to have, and then define a sequence so that $f(x_{i-1})-2f(x_i)+f(x_{i+1})=c$ for all $i$.  In particular, this can be achieved by setting

$$x_{i+1} = f^{-1}(c-f(x_{i-1})+2f(x_i)).$$

Iterate this until you get to $x_n$.  Now if you just choose $a',c$ haphazardly, then the final value $x_n$ may be larger or smaller than $b$, so this doesn't immediately solve the problem.

Instead, our goal will be to find $a',c$ that makes this work.  Define $g(a',c)$ to be the value of $x_n$ you get when you use the values $a',c$ above.  For your class of functions, $g(a',c)$ should be a monotonically increasing function of $a'$ and of $c$, so you can now try to find $a',c$ such that $g(a',c)=b$ by using any standard method for such a problem -- e.g., binary search, Newton's method, etc.